# perc 6/i monitoring with megacli on non dell mobo

Tags: linux, hardware-raid, perc6

I currently have a perc 6/i sitting in my GA-G41M-ES2L running ubuntu server 10.04. While I am able to use my array, and everything works fine, I am unable to use megacli to get monitoring output. I've tried CentOS and openSUSE and nothing works.

I was trying to fix it the other day with a friend, and he came to the conclusion that the address space of the motherboard was conflicting with that of the card.

Is my motherboard the problem? If so, are there any non-dell motherboards that will play nicely with the perc 6/i

Comment: what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did the tape mod, (taping lanes 5 and 6) and now megacli works like a charm.